# Windows 2008 r2 firewall rdp rule and linux rdesktop

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, windows-firewall

I have a production Windows 2008 R2 server, and my workstation is Gentoo linux (kernel 3.12.13). I used to connect to server with rdesktop.

Now I want to restrict the windows firewall rule for rdp (built-in rule) to allow connections from certain IPs only. Firewall demands that only secure rdp connections can be restricted and gives me 4 options:

- allow the connection if it's authenticated and integrity protected
- require the connections to be encrypted
- allow the connection to use null encapsulation
- override block rules

I don't know which option is supported by my Gentoo rdesktop.

1. What type should I choose?
2. Should I modify rdesktop parameters and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to the `Scope` tab of the firewall rule and add your workstations ip address to the `Remote ip address` section.

Leave the action on the `General` tab set to `Allow the connection`.